# How a LocalPod can add dependency of a same name

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

I have a local pod with a name `LocalPod`

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'LocalPod'
  s.version          = '0.1.1'
  s.summary          = 'Local Pod Module'
  s.description      = 'my description'
  s.homepage         = 'https://git.mylocalpod.com/'
  s.license          = 'local'
  s.author           = 'self'
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  s.dependency 'LocalPod', '0.1.1'
  s.source_files = 'LocalPod/src/**/*'
  
end
```

It requires to get another dependencies with the same name `LocalPod` from another repo

So when I do `pod install --repo-update` it will error state

```
[!] Invalid `LocalPod.podspec` file: [!] A specification can't require itself as a subspec.
```

How can I work around this issue without the need to change my `LocalPod` name to another name?

Comment: I think you can specify the repo path for the dependency, eg.  `s.dependency 'LocalPod', :git => "https://github.com/..../LocalPod"`

Comment: Don't seems to work :(

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's possible. CocoaPods has many implicit assumptions about names being unique.